# Здраствуйте, я работаю на Electron JS, и я б хотел подключить Python файл

Tags: node.js, electron

Здраствуйте, я работаю на Electron JS, и я б хотел подключить Python файл дабы разширить свои возможности.

**Как подключить, и заставить работать в связке Python(с модулями) и Electron JS**

Comment: На сайте proglib.io есть статья "Соединяем Python и Electron/Node.js в приложении для десктопа". Сам хочу опробовать. Надеюсь поможет.